# can not load javascript class inside node modules in webpack

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I have created and publish a custom npm package and i included that package in my webapck entry file.But i can not call function inside that npm class in my html file.Here is my npm package

```
 export default class myClass{
        constructor(getVar){
            this.params     =   {
                signLength : (getVar.signLength !=undefined)?getVar.signLength:null,
                canvas     : (getVar.canvas !=undefined)?getVar.canvas:null,
                linecolor  : (getVar.linecolor !=undefined)?getVar.linecolor:null,
                pointSize  : (getVar.pointSize !=undefined)?getVar.pointSize:null,
                xstarting  : '',
                ystarting  : ''
            }; 
...........................
```

And i have included that in to my webpack entry file

```
const myClass = require('npm pack name').default;
module.exports = myClass;
```

and i am trying to call that in my html file

```
setParams.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
    myClass.draw(e);
  },false);
```

but i am getting this error

> index.html:24 Uncaught ReferenceError: myClass is not defined

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access myClass into your html file because it's encapsulated and not a global variable.

To solve this problem, you should use js file and import myclass into that file.

```
const myClass = require('path_to_my_class');
setParams.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
    myClass.draw(e);
  },false);
```

Or, if you want really access myclass to your html, you need to use a global variable which is not recommanded but should work.

```
window.myclass = require('npm pack name').default;
```

**Note:** `require().default` is a constructor, maybe you need the keyword `new` to instance it.

Comment: i tried second method ...but i am getting error..let objMyClass      = new myClass(setParams); Uncaught ReferenceError: myClass is not defined

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: myClass is not defined

Comment: You mean, using window.myclass = require... ?

Comment: window.myclass = require('npm pack namen').default;
module.exports = myClass;

Comment: Where did you define myClass? Maybe it's because the case. Should be window.myClass = require ...; module.exports = window.myClass

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195529/discussion-between-sandeep-nambiar-and-radonirina-maminiaina).